# html Won't wrap around bloginfo('whatever')

Tags: wordpress, function

I have a function that inserts my header information in wordpress site. However when I use:

```
echo '<h1>'.bloginfo('name').'</h1>';
```

or

```
echo '<a href="'.bloginfo('url').'">Some url</a>';
```

It outputs:

```
Blog Name
<h1></h1>
```

or

```
Url
<a href=""></>
```

It won't wrap it in the html tags. 
thanks for your help in advance

Comment: When I run it, I get *Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or `';''*. You have very obvious syntax errors in your code. Provide a real [mcve]

Comment: You say you can't find any information yet you post an error message telling you why?

Comment: Sorry about that I misplaced some apostrophes, I have edited

Comment: @ProEvilz — I'm not bilcker. My comment addresses them as "you". bilcker and I don't even have similar usernames.

Comment: My bad - but OP, use `get_bloginfo()` as `bloginfo()` already essentially has an echo applied to it. Bare this in mind moving forward when using other WP functions. There will two versions just like this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing this:

`echo '<h1>'.bloginfo('name').'</h1>';`

instead of this

`echo '<h1>.'bloginfo('name')'.</h1>';`

( To get free of the syntax error )

Although, to return the blog name without echoing it you can use:

`echo '<h1>'.get_bloginfo('name').'</h1>';`

Comment: While that will fix the syntax error described in my comment, I don't see how it will fix the problem described in the question.

Comment: that's what was missing, thanks get_bloginfo() worked. Brains not working this morning.